# Angular Failed to instantiate module after renaming it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, initialization

I had an Angular module named "sample" and angular debugging console was asking me to rename it to "appname.sample", I did that and I also changed the calling of the module. 
But angular seems to be still looking for module sample. and I am getting the error:

$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module decisionone due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Where else am I supposed to change it?

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('appname.sample', ['ngRoute', 'common', 'ngSanitize'])
```

and when I am including it:
angular.module('appname.sample')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be maybe that you made already a different module dependent on your `sample` module something like this:

```
angular.module('someDifferentModule', ['sample'])
```

If so you have to rename it here as well:

```
angular.module('someDifferentModule', ['appname.sample'])
```

Also, based on the Angular error, it seems that the problem is not with your app.sample but rather with a module named `decisionone`

> $injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module **decisionone** due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Are you injecting this some where like this:

```
angular.module('someModule', ['decisionone'])
```

and `desicionone` was never instantiated as a module?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your config file/route file for that module some where else. Make sure you are also changing that module name.

For example in ngRoute if config and rout specification are defined separately I also need to make module name to be same.

```
angular.module('appname.sample', []);

angular.module('appname.sample').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/urlPath", {
                controller: 'controllerName',
                templateUrl: 'modules/pathToViewPage/view.html',
            });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html file page you should have ng-app="your module name" on a tag somewhere, probably the body tag. Change this to match your new module name.